# sorting an array - keep getting errors.

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

i have a project in c++ -i receive an array, and i need to build a program that will print only the numbers that appears more than 3 times + their index's.
for example, for the array 6,4,4,5,2,4,4,3,5,5 - it will print:
4: 1,2,5,6
5: 3,8,9

and the most important - it should be no more than O(n*log n).

sooo....for the problem...

this is the error i keep getting:

```
    1>HW - 2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl mergeSortP(int *         const,int)" (?mergeSortP@@YAXQAHH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl checkIfNumberIsMoreThenThreeTimes(int * const,int)" (?checkIfNumberIsMoreThenThreeTimes@@YAXQAHH@Z)
1>C:\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\HW - 2\Debug\HW - 2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

and this is the code:

```
void checkIfNumberIsMoreThenThreeTimes(int arr[], int n)
{
    int **p;
    p = copyToPointersArr(arr, n);
    mergeSortP(*p, n);
    output( arr, p, n);
}
```

//

```
int** copyToPointersArr(int *arr, int n)
{
    int **pointers;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        *pointers[i]=arr[i];
    return pointers;
}
```

//

```
void merge(int **a1, int **a2, int size1, int size2, int **res)
{
    int ind1, ind2, ind;
    ind1=ind2=ind=0;
    while (ind1<size1 && ind2<size2)
    {
        if (*a1[ind1]<=*a2[ind2])
        {
            res[ind]=a1[ind1];
            ind1++;
        }
        else
        {
            res[ind]=a2[ind2];
            ind2++;
        }
        ind++;
    }
    while (ind1<size1)
    {
        res[ind]=a1[ind1];
        ind1++;
        ind++;
    }
    while (ind2<size2)
    {
        res[ind]=a2[ind2];
        ind2++;
        ind++;
    }
}
```

//

```
void mergeSortP(int **a, int size)
{
    int i;
    int **temp=NULL;
    if (size==1)
        return;
    else
    {
        mergeSortP(a, size/2);
        mergeSortP(a+(size/2), size-(size/2));
        temp = new int* [size];
        merge(a, a+(size/2), size/2 , size-(size/2), temp);
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            a[i] = temp[i];
        delete []temp;
        temp=NULL;
    }
 }
```

//

```
void output(int arr[], int **ptr,int size)
{

    int i, j, count=0;
    for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        if(*ptr[i]==*ptr[i+1]) 
            count++;
        else if (count>=2) 
        {
            cout << *ptr[i] << ": ";
            for (j = count; j >= 0; j--)
                cout << (ptr[i-j]-arr) << ", ";
            count=0;
        }
        else
            count=0;
    }
}
```

please help!!!
thanks in advance....

Comment: mergeSortP wants a double pointer. You are trying to pass single pointer.

Comment: @user3328918 - Pardon my ignorance, but how does using a merge sort solve your issue, i.e. count the number of times a number occurs in an array and list the indices?  If you're really learning C++, then the obvious solution would be to use a std::map<int, SomeStruct> where SomeStruct is a struct that contains a count and a vector that contains the indices found.  Probably 5 or 6 lines, 10 at most to write.

Comment: I agree with @PaulMcKenzie.  Is this really what passes for C++ education these days?  _Double_ pointers?  Don't people learning C++ have enough trouble with _regular_ pointers?

Comment: @user3328918 - Just for laughs, I coded a solution using a map<int, vector<int>>. With block braces on separate lines, the program was 39 lines long, and this included the output generation, header file includes, a couple of typedefs, blank lines for "nice looking code", etc. The "meat" of the program (the gathering and counting of the numbers) took a loop that consisted of 4 lines. I'm only saying this because of the difference between those stats and what you posted. If you were to actually learn C++, I would bet your code would come close to what I was able to write, believe me.

Comment: @user3328918 - I forgot, it also completes the job in logarithmic time, just as your requirements stated.

Comment: hi again, thanks for helping, but we (the class) didn't learn vectors.... can you please help me with the code i have written?

Comment: Change the merge functions to use int * instead of int **. Either do this using local int *, or change the parameters. Side note - a bottom up merge sort would be more efficient than a top down merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

In `void checkIfNumberIsMoreThenThreeTimes(int arr[], int n)`, you have

```
int **p;
```

and

```
mergeSortP(*p, n);
```

So the first argument to `mergeSortP` is of type `int*`.

However, you only have a function

```
void mergeSortP(int **a, int size)
```

so the linker complains because it can't find it. Maybe you meant to call

```
mergeSortP(p, n);
```

instead?

Comment: i tried to do it, but then i get the error:
    'mergeSortP' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int **' to 'int []'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Answer (score 0):

Following may help: https://ideone.com/oiAzTh

```
void displayFrequentNumber(const std::vector<int>& input)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::size_t>> v;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != input.size(); ++i) {
        v.push_back({input[i], i});
    }
    std::sort(begin(v), end(v));
    for (auto it = begin(v); it != end(v); ) {
        auto next = find_if(it, end(v),
                            [it](const std::pair<int, std::size_t>& rhs)
                                {return it->first != rhs.first;});
        if (next - it >= 3) {
            std::cout << it->first << ":";
            for (; it != next; ++it) {
                std::cout << " " << it->second;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        it = next;
    }
}
```